# Conversion of VMware terminal server VM to Hyper-V now has stretched screen across multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

Extremely bizarre issue here.
Recently I've converted a Windows Server 2008R2 terminal server from VMware to Hyper-V using MVMC. After re-activating the license, it was put into production.

Now, here's where things get strange:
Our environment has users on the little Wyse thin clients which all get **the same** configuration from an FTP server and everyone has two monitors. The clients all connect to either of two terminal servers (one is the converted one, one is not). A **select few** clients get stretched screens on their connections and others do not.

- If I get the same user with the issue to use a different thin client,
  the issue disappears, and vice-versa when I get a user without the
  issue to use the affected box.
- If I go into Display Settings, it    shows one monitor that has the
  width of the two combined. I'm unable    to change it as it complains
  it is a remote desktop connection.
- SCVMM shows that the max screens has been set to 1, but it's greyed out and I'm unable to change it
- Some Googling reveals the issue could be related to RemoteFX, but I'm unable to install that as it requires Hyper-V which I'm also unable to install as these are Virtual Machines, not bare metal
- If an affected user connects to the non-converted terminal server, this issue does not appear

Below is a screenshot of the Display Settings window. There are in fact two monitors but as you can see, only one comically long one appears.

Any ideas?

[image: Stretchy Screen Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.
Thanks to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/637251/what-would-cause-wyse-c10le-thin-clients-to-suddenly-be-unable-to-use-dual-displ) I uninstalled windows update **KB2984972** and I was back in business.

[Link to KB2984972](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2984972/update-for-rdc-7.1-to-support-restricted-administration-logons-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2)